# Faerzress and other teleportation spells

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, teleportation, out-of-the-abyss

In the D&D 5e module Out of the Abyss, one effect of faerzress is:

> Any creature attempting to teleport into, within, or out of a faerzress-suffused area must succeed on a DC 15 Constitution saving throw. On a failed save, the creature takes 1d10 force damage and the teleportation attempt fails. Even if the save succeeds, the teleportation attempt can suffer a mishap as if the destination was known only by description, regardless of how familiar the destination actually is. See the table in the teleport spell for more information.

So if I attempt to teleport in faerzress, I have a chance of teleporting to a "similar area". I presume that this also applies to spells other than teleport, such as misty step and dimension door. But under "similar area" it says:

> Generally, you appear in the closest similar place, but since the spell has no range limit, you could conceivably wind up anywhere on the plane.

So if I misty step in faerzress, make the CON save, and roll 45 on 1d100 ("similar area"), can I be teleported anywhere on the plane, or only as far as misty step can teleport me (30 feet)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Most likely not

The Teleport spell you quoted states:

> Generally, you appear in the closest similar place, but since the spell has no range limit, you could conceivably wind up anywhere on the plane.

This seems to be a clear implication that the teleport mishap won't violate the range limitation of the spell in question. If the mishap could send you outside of the spell's original range, writing "**since** the spell has no range limit" as the reason for potentially ending on the other side of the planet would not make much sense.